# How to get httprequest and httpresponse in ApplicationListener in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to set browser cookie value after login successfully. 
I am able to detect success login event with following code.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoginEventListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {

        log.info("hahaha: " + event.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try autowiring `HttpServletRequest` object into your `LoginEventListener` component, given that your component in running in a servlet container.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoginEventListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;    

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        log.info("hahaha: " + event.toString());
        log.info("Request Object: " + request); // You now have access to the HTTP request object.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tks, just share another way to get it.

```
HttpServletRequest request =
                ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.
                        currentRequestAttributes()).
                        getRequest();
```